# ¿Cómo puedo poner un color de fondo a mi título, pero que si mi título ocupa varias lineas el color no se vea en el interlineado?

Tags: html, css, background

Lo intenté utilizando un "span" y si reduce el background a solo el texto, pero se siguen viendo juntos el de abajo con el de arriba. También intenté crear un nuevo "span" con la parte del titulo que quedaba abajo, pero tampoco sirvió.

¿Que puedo hacer?

[image: Imagen referencial]

[image: Imagen referencial]

```css
.back {
    background-color: #AFA34F;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#hh {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 250%;
}

#Titulo {
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 380px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Titulo">
<h1 id="hh"><span class="back">Este es un texto de prueba para mostrar<span class="back"><br>lo que obtengo con mi código</span></span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 50vw;
}

h1 span {
    background-color: cyan;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet provident nisi eum fugit reprehenderit cumque.</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Mejor añade una explicación al dar una respuesta de que es lo que le hace falta, que es lo que hace...

Comment: Hola. En span solo agregaría el background-color de ese modo solo será el texto el que tenga el fondo y en h1 agrega `línea-height` para darle el espacio que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

En span solo agregaría el background-color de ese modo solo será el texto el que tenga el fondo y en h1 agrega línea-height para darle el espacio que necesites.

Algo así

```
`
<style>
#hh {
color: black;
text-align: center;
font-size: 250%;
line-height: 60px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;

}
#hh span {
background-color: #AFA34F;
}
#Titulo {
width: 65%;
margin: 0px auto;
position: relative;
top: 380px;
}
</style>

<div id="Titulo">
<h1 id="hh"><span>Este es un texto de prueba para mostrar lo que obtengo con mi código</span></h1>
</div>`
```